# How to write if condition to check numbers greater than or less than in php?

Tags: php, if-statement

> I have one input field where user will add numbers and in next label
> it will display that numbers in words. Basically user will input
> amount in number format and it will display in word format.And i have
> some conditions to show amount in words.

First condition is Amount should not greater than 10 digits.

Second condition is user can add money in decimal format.

e.g : this is `1000000000.90` Allow (10 digits and then decimal point)

e.g : this is `10000000000.90` Not Allow (decimal point after eleven digit)

So basically Amount length can go upto `13` digits with decimal point.

Without decimal Point it should be upto `10`

For this I write below condition :

```
if(amount.length > 13){
   return 'please enter less amount';
}
if(amount.length > 10 && amount.includes('.') === false){
 return 'please enter less amount';
}
```

> When i enter 11 digits and then decimal point `10000000000.0` it shows
> me amount in words but i want here to display error message because
> before decimal point there should be only 10 digits are allowed

So. Basically I want condition for allowd amount with decimal 13 digits and without decimal 1 digits only.please help me to solve this scenario. thanks in advance.

Comment: There is https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php which matches what you are doing in JS. That doesn't check value though. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php would be the equivalent of `includes ` You can do `$_POST[...] > X` and same for less than. 13 digits may exceed the max integer size. Also could use a regex `^\d{1,10}` for up to 10 integers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you want to allow numbers with those conditions so rather then use strlen and other functions why not just use maths.

Example

```
<?php
if($number <= 9999999999.99)
{
//Run the allowed code here
}
else
{
//Not allowed
}
?>
```